# Windows shell add item to protected folder {2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}

Tags: windows, shell, registry, directory, contextmenu

I want to make a small program that locks folders with password and unlocks with that password again. I can do it with adding some special Class Ids to folder name. (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con)

Also, I want to add this feature to windows right click context menu for folders.(-> Lock & Unlock this folder)

I can add new items to folders via "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell" successfully. It seems when a folder is not locked. But after a folder is locked, the item is not seem on right click context. I have tried with several nodes of regedit but no one is succeeded.

How can I add a new item to right click context of all folders (include locked folders)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your command in the key for the CLSID you used to "lock" the folder.

If you use the "lock GUID" ({2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}) then you must add your [verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-verbs) under "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}\shell"

Comment: Thanks very much! After giving some permissions, it could be added succesfully. So, what about giving these permissions when adding regedit keys with C# program. Will I need give these permissions when install locker program on a new computer? Can I give these permissions with c# code, or must I do it manually from regedit?

Comment: You can add the entry to HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}\shell..., it is per-user and does not require admin access.